# In Mint 20.2 with Mate, is it possible to close all the open windows of the File Manager?

Tags: linux-mint, windows, mate-desktop, file-manager

I use Mint 20.2 with Mate File Manager.

I am new to Linux, and I am a long time user of MacOS.

I am looking for a way to close all the open windows of the File Manager with one command, possibly just using a keyboard shortcut (as I am used to do in MacOS).

I am aware I may need to create a script and associate it to a keyboard shortcut, in that case could you help me with that.
I am open to any solution that allow me to use just one shortcut, without leaving the File Manager.

Comment: You could create a shortcut with `killall caja` :D

Comment: that would be great! is there a way to associate the script to an element in the panel? and/or to a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: `killall caja` works but is a bit dirty but you can use `caja -q`. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use the `caja -q` command
You can create a **keyboard shortcut** like this:

1. **Open shortcuts window:** System->Preferences->Hardware->Keyboard Shortcuts
2. **Create new shortcut:** Click the *Add* button. Set the name you like e.g. `Close all caja windows` and set the Command to `caja -q`. Then click Apply
3. **Set the screenshot you want:** Double click where it says *Disabled* and press your preferred Key combo, e.g. *"Ctrl+Shif+q"*

or a **panel applet** like this:

1. **add panel item:** right click on the panel, select the *Add* button and add a *"Custom Application Launcher"*.
2. **Create new launcher:** Set the name you like e.g. `Close all caja windows` and set the Command to `caja -q` (Type: App or App in Terminal, Comment: how you like it, Picture: how you like it. Then click Ok

Hope this helps!